# ¿Cómo corregir el dato que retorna este método a partir de un array?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy aprendiendo Java y ando creando un pequeño programa con varias clases que heredan de otra.
Donde basicamente el programa trata de un concesionario que tiene varios vehiculos a la venta tanto motos como coches; y luego tu como usuario te puedes registrar y tal.

La cuestion es que he creado una funcion que recibe un array de tipo string de 2 valores, donde cada uno de esos valores los utiliza luego para devolver un Objeto de tipo coche o moto dependiendo el contenido de ese array.
En principìo esa funcion funciona perfecta,le paso un array con los strings correctos, y me devuelve un objeto; pero cuando le paso un array donde sus valores fueron introducidos a partir de un string que se pidio al usuario; me devuelve null, es decir nunca llega a devolver ningun objeto.
Y lo mas curioso es que imprimo en pantalla dicho array, y realmente se relleno correctamente esas posiciones.

De esta manera funciona todo correcto y me devuelva las caracteristicas del vehiculo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    //Creo un array de 2 posiciones donde le introduzco esos valores
    String[] respuesta = new String[2];
    respuesta[0] = "moto";
    respuesta[1] = "deportiva";
    
    //le paso a la funcion concesionario el array como parametro, y como devuelve un objeto, llama a un metodo de la clase 
    
    System.out.println(Concesionario(respuesta).SpecsVehiculo());
```

esta es la funcion que llama desde el main que crea objetos de tipo coche o moto dependiendo de los valores en las posiciones 0 y 1 del array pasado por parametro.

```
    //La funcion que llama desde el main y que devuelve Objetos de tipo vehiculo
    static Vehiculo Concesionario(String[] vehiculoModelo)
    {
        
        Moto scooter = new Moto();
        if(vehiculoModelo[0]== "moto")
        {
            switch(vehiculoModelo[1])
            {
                
                case "deportiva":
                    Moto deportiva = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "600cc", 110, 8400);
                    return deportiva;
                case "turismo":
                    Moto turismo = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "1200cc", 140, 18500);
                    return turismo;
                case "enduro":
                    Moto enduro = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "250cc", 25, 5200);
                    return enduro;
                default:
                    return scooter;
            }
        }
        else if(vehiculoModelo[0]== "coche")
        {
            Coche sedan = new Coche();
            switch(vehiculoModelo[1])
            {
                
                case "deportivo":
                    Coche deportivo = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "3.0 tfsi","Trasera","Gasolina",3, 350, "Secuencial 6 marchas", 65400);
                    return deportivo;
                case "offroad":
                    Coche offroad = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "2.5 tdi","4x4","Diesel",5, 150, "Manual 5 marchas", 31700);
                    return offroad;
                case "familiar":
                    Coche familiar = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "1.8 eco burst","4x4","Gasolina hibrido",5, 120, "Automatico", 28500);
                    return familiar;
                default:
                    return sedan;
            }
        } else return null;
                
    }
```

Pero de esta manera me devuelve null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        //Creo un array de 2 posiciones donde le introduzco esos valores
        String[] respuesta = new String[2];
        System.out.print("escribe moto o coche: ");
        respuesta[0] = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("escribe el modelo: ");
        respuesta[1] = scanner.nextLine();
        
        //le paso a la funcion concesionario el array como parametro, y como devuelve un objeto, llama a un metodo de la clase 
        //vehiculo que devuelve las caracteristicas del vehiculo devuelto por el array
        
        System.out.println(Concesionario(respuesta).SpecsVehiculo());
```

[image: Introduciendo los valores manualmente funciona]

[image: Introduciendo los valores por el usuario me lanzar este error]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! es muy probable que estes comparando strings, y que este mal esa comparacion (asi sea porque las cadenas tienen un enter al final, o algun otro motivo)... deberias mostrar esa parte...

Comment: Muestra tu clase `Concesionario`  y muéstranos también una salida por pantalla del contenido de `respuesta` en el contexto donde dices que está fallando. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un problema conocido de java, estas utilizando el comparador "==". En objetos este lo que hace es comprobar que te estes refiriendo a la misma instancia, en el caso de introducir tu "a fuego" los datos por el funcionamiento interno de la JDK permite que sea la misma instancia, en cambio cuando lo introduces manualmente no.

Para solucionarlo utiliza el comparador .equals(), pertenece a Object, y por tanto lo tine cualquier objeto java. Cuando te familiarizes con el uso de este metodo lo puedes sobreescirbir.

Esto deberia funcionar:

```
static Vehiculo Concesionario(String[] vehiculoModelo)
{
    
    Moto scooter = new Moto();
    if(vehiculoModelo[0].equals("moto"))
    {
        switch(vehiculoModelo[1])
        {
            
            case "deportiva":
                Moto deportiva = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "600cc", 110, 8400);
                return deportiva;
            case "turismo":
                Moto turismo = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "1200cc", 140, 18500);
                return turismo;
            case "enduro":
                Moto enduro = new Moto(vehiculoModelo[1], "250cc", 25, 5200);
                return enduro;
            default:
                return scooter;
        }
    }
    else if(vehiculoModelo[0].equals("coche"))
    {
        Coche sedan = new Coche();
        switch(vehiculoModelo[1])
        {
            
            case "deportivo":
                Coche deportivo = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "3.0 tfsi","Trasera","Gasolina",3, 350, "Secuencial 6 marchas", 65400);
                return deportivo;
            case "offroad":
                Coche offroad = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "2.5 tdi","4x4","Diesel",5, 150, "Manual 5 marchas", 31700);
                return offroad;
            case "familiar":
                Coche familiar = new Coche(vehiculoModelo[1], "1.8 eco burst","4x4","Gasolina hibrido",5, 120, "Automatico", 28500);
                return familiar;
            default:
                return sedan;
        }
    } else return null;
            
}
```